# Как визуально редактировать скрытый контент в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как в wordpress дать конечному пользователю (без знания кода) возможность редактировать скрытый контент? Например, при нажатии на определенную кнопку появляется (изначально скрытый) див блок, который имеет текст, картинки и прочее содержимое?

---

Я предполагаю что это содержимое можно запихнуть в фреймворк, где дать возможность изменять цвета блоков, менять текст и картинки. Ведь возможно? Но в большей степени интересует визуальное редактирование непосредственно на странице в режиме реального времени. Это можно реализовать? И как?

Comment: Поставьте плагин Elementor, например, и не мучайтесь. Или дождитесь Гутенберг в WordPress 5.0.

Comment: Он позволит редактировать скрытый контент непосредственно на странице? Но ведь редактор работает тактильно, и чтобы показать скрытый контент необходимо произвести взаимодействие с каким-то элементом (скажем, нажать на кнопку). И мне кажется он предложит её стилизовать и только. И не покажет скрытый контент. Или я не совсем понимаю принцип работы?)

Comment: Вы не понимаете, чего хотите. А чтобы понять, надо изучить то, что уже сделано до вас. Вы не дискутируйте, а попробуйте.

Comment: Что такое вообще " скрытый контент"? Где, как сделано, для чего нужно?. Исправь вопрос, ответив на это.

Comment: @SeVlad да тут уже не первый вопрос на эту тему. Из контекста догадываюсь, что речь идёт о "скрытом" html/css)

Comment: @KAGGDesign давай дадим возможность  ТСу правильно сформулировать задачу. (и не стоит учить неправильному - пользоваться разными мышевозкам ;) )

Comment: @SeVlad ну, во-первых, я уже пытался выяснить, что же нужно. Но, как говорится, самое сложное - это понять, чего же на самом деле мы хотим. А во-вторых, не ты ли говорил, что каждый второй ответ на SO может быть закрыт упоминанием плагинов?))

Comment: Так что мне в итоге использовать? Один говорит "неправильно" - другой "правильно". Мне что для этого использовать? Elementor, фреймворку или что то другое?

Comment: @KAGGDesign даже не каждый второй, а процентов 80 %). Но не все --йогурты-- плагины стоит использовать ;) Мышевозки-зло. А тем более на SO.

Comment: @БогданГётте, прежде чем "что-то" использовать нужно сформулировать задачу. Ответь на наводящие вопросы.

Comment: @SeVlad, вам ведь сказали, что я подразумеваю изначально скрытые html и css. Важно понять, как конечный пользователь, который не знаком с кодом, может визуально этот скрытый контент редактировать?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, я предполагаю что это можно реализовать в Customizer.  Изначально этот элемент скрыть и в Customizer сделать две настройки "Hide" и "show". Там же сделать настройки по стилизации каждого элемента в этом "скрытом контенте". Теоретически возможно? Или можно как-то проще?

Comment: Можно и так, можно и ещё десятком других способов. Но Customizer - ok, стандартный подход. Пока нет чёткого описания задачи, трудно ответить.

Comment: @KAGGDesign на днях постараюсь сделать "образец", позволяющий вам понять лучше, что мне необходимо. Скажите, а как лучше сделать визуальное редактирование для пользователя (themeforest) своей темы? Через Customizer, через фреймворк или, может, еще как-то? Какие есть способы?

Comment: Делайте так, как знаете, и как вам удобно

Comment: @KAGGDesign мне более важно, чтобы было удобно пользователю

Comment: > ведь сказали, что я подразумеваю изначально скрытые html и css. //// Я может тебя удивлю, но любой сайт на выходе - это html. + нередко css и js. Но не умеешь задать вопрос - что ж...

Comment: @KAGGDesign, видишь - и этот хочет на themeforest.:) Почему я и говорю - это помойка. Только платная :)

Comment: Тогда что вам непонятно, @SeVlad? 3 простых слова: редактировать скрытое содержимое. И если вам до сих пор непонятно, что вы забыли в этой "дискуссии" и на этом форуме в принципе?

Comment: Мне не понятно только одно - зачем ты просишь помощь, игнорируя https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-wordpress?noredirect=1#comment1354336_843675